# how to make a setNickname command in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a *Change Nickname* command in **discord.js v13**, and It's not working.
My code:

```js
            const target = message.mentions.members.first();
            const nickname = args.slice(1).join(' ');
            if (!target) return message.channel.send('Please specify a target to change nickname');
            if (!nickname) return message.channel.send('Please specify a nickname to change');


            target.setNickname(nickname);
```

I am using node.js v16

[image: The Commands]

[image: This user's nickname should change to oskol]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working for me, but make sure your bot has the following Permissions and the bot's role is above the role of the users who want to edit his nick:
Change this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKP9h.png
To this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX8GF.png
Also make sure your command is lowercase because uppercase characters are not allowed in command names.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw a guess that the nickname you are trying to set is null or empty, this will cause discord to just reset the nickname to the users normal discord username.

Make sure to debug the values that are being passed on and providing such information when making a question on here as it will help people more easily help you.

With that said, the below code worked fine for me

```
    const target = msg.mentions.members.first();
    if (!target) return msg.reply('Please mention a user');
    const nick = args[1];
    if (!nick) return msg.reply('Please provide a nickname');
    const oldNick = target.nickname;
    if (oldNick === nick) return msg.reply('That user already has that nickname');
    console.log(`Changing ${target.user.tag}'s nickname from ${oldNick} to ${nick}`);
    target.setNickname('');
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided seems to work correctly. The error might be your bot's intents. Make sure that you enabled/requested all intents you need for this command (guild members if I remember correctly). Make sure that you also gave your bot the required permissions: `MANAGE_NICKNAMES` in the server settings (roles).

Good luck!